# Time dimension table in SQLPlus

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing a datawarehouse project for college with Oracle Database (SQLPlus).
I need to create the time dimension table and to populate it. The table needs to be like this:

[image]

It needs to go from 2004 to 2019.

I've tried different things and queries that I've found but they don't works and, sadly, I don't know enough about SQLPlus to create one on my own (or to successfully modify one). I'm completely lost.

Thank you very much for your help and patience.

Comment: Hello! Please provide any steps you have tried so far and what error are you getting? Have you followed any of [Oracle tutorials](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-create-table/) on creating tables?

Comment: Yes. I can create the table without any problem, but I don't know how to automatically populate it with all the data that I need (all the days from 1/1/2004 to 31/12/2019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table date_dim
(id number(38),
date date,
id_dayofweek number(38),
dayofweek varchar(100),
id_holiday number(38),
 id_month number(38),
 month varchar(100),  
 id_year number(38),
 id_total number(38),
 Total varchar(100));
```

Use above query to create the table.

Regarding the data, you can generate it through connect by clause.

```
insert into date_dim
(select level as id, to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level as date1,   
case when ltrim(rtrim(to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Day'))) = 'Monday' then 2
when ltrim(rtrim(to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Day'))) = 'Tuesday' then 3
when ltrim(rtrim(to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Day'))) = 'Wednesday' then 4
when ltrim(rtrim(to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Day'))) = 'Thursday' then 5
when ltrim(rtrim(to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Day'))) = 'Friday' then 6
when ltrim(rtrim(to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Day'))) = 'Saturday' then 7
when ltrim(rtrim(to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Day'))) = 'Sunday' then 1 end as id_dayofweek,
to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Day') as dayofweek,
0 as id_holiday,
to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'MM') as id_month,
to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'Month') as month,
to_char(to_date('31-DEC-2003', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + level, 'YYYY') as year,
1 as id_total,
'Total' as Total
from dual
connect by level < = 5844);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I need to create this table and populate it with the days from 1 January 2004 to 31 December 2019.

Comment: Then use the date column,

Comment: How can I do it? I need to populate the table. Sorry I can't understand what query should I use

Comment: Oh you need to create table and populate the values?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need the table to have those columns and to have data from 2004 to 2019. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Provided you the ddl statement to create the table. Do you want to insert the data as well?

Comment: You are welcome, can you please make this answer correct and also upvote, so that others will also be helpful

Comment: Yes, absolutely, with pleasure. As soon as you change it to include the query I will gladly mark it as correct and upvote. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you created the table. Now what is your requirement?

Comment: I have created it, now I need to automatically insert all the rows with id, date, id_DayOfWeek, DayOfWeek... (like the rows in the image) going from 1 Janurary 2004 to 31 December 2019. Thanks

Comment: Got it, your data is in a file?

Comment: Nope, no file. I need the db to do it automatically. I've tried with a few scripts found online, but none had the right columns and I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: Provided you the solution

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect. Exactly what I needed. FYI, I just needed to change the name of the column date to day, since "date" is an Oracle reserved word. Thanks once again, you helped me a lot. (I've upvoted your answer, it registers the vote, but it doesn't change the overall score because of my low reputation)

Comment: Yes that's correct data is an Oracle reserved key word. Hope you got what you need

Answer (score 1):

Do not store all the columns; use virtual columns instead to calculate derived data otherwise you will find that your columns could be inconsistent:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id             NUMBER(10,0)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                 CONSTRAINT table_name__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  "DATE"         DATE
                 CONSTRAINT table_name__date__nn NOT NULL
                 CONSTRAINT table_name__date__u UNIQUE
                 CONSTRAINT table_name__date__chk CHECK ( "DATE" = TRUNC( "DATE" ) ),
  id_day_of_week NUMBER(1,0) 
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( "DATE" - TRUNC( "DATE", 'IW' ) + 1 ),
  day_of_week    VARCHAR2(9)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CAST( TRIM( TO_CHAR( "DATE", 'DAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN' ) ) AS VARCHAR2(9) ) ),
  is_holiday     NUMBER(1,0)
                 CONSTRAINT table_name__id_holiday__chk CHECK ( is_holiday IN ( 0, 1 ) ),
  id_month       NUMBER(2,0)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM "DATE" ) ),
  month          VARCHAR2(9)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CAST( TRIM( TO_CHAR( "DATE", 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN' ) ) AS VARCHAR2(9) ) ),
  id_year        NUMBER(5,0)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM "DATE" ) ),
  id_total       NUMBER(1,0)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 1 ),
  total          CHAR(5)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 'Total' )
);
```

*Note:*

- *You should not name the column `DATE` as its a keyword and you will need to surround it in double-quotes and use the same case every time you use it.*
- *The `id_day_of_week` is based on the day of the ISO8601 week because relying on `TO_CHAR( "DATE", 'D' )` depends on the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting as to which day of the week is the first day; this way it is independent of any settings.*
- *The `day_of_week` and `month` columns have a fixed language.*
- *It is unclear what `id_total` and `total` should contain so these are generated as literal values; if you want to have non-static data in these columns then remove the `GENERATED ...` part of the declaration.*

Then you can populate it using:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( "DATE", is_holiday )
SELECT DATE '2004-01-01' + LEVEL - 1, 0
FROM  DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2004-01-01' + LEVEL - 1 < DATE '2020-01-01';
```

And update the holiday dates using an `UPDATE` statement according to your territory.

Then if you do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY "DATE" ASC
FETCH FIRST 32 ROWS ONLY;
```

The output is:

> ```
> ID | DATE      | ID_DAY_OF_WEEK | DAY_OF_WEEK | IS_HOLIDAY | ID_MONTH | MONTH    | ID_YEAR | ID_TOTAL | TOTAL
> -: | :-------- | -------------: | :---------- | ---------: | -------: | :------- | ------: | -------: | :----
>  1 | 01-JAN-04 |              4 | THURSDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
>  2 | 02-JAN-04 |              5 | FRIDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
>  3 | 03-JAN-04 |              6 | SATURDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
>  4 | 04-JAN-04 |              7 | SUNDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
>  5 | 05-JAN-04 |              1 | MONDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
>  6 | 06-JAN-04 |              2 | TUESDAY     |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
>  7 | 07-JAN-04 |              3 | WEDNESDAY   |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
>  8 | 08-JAN-04 |              4 | THURSDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
>  9 | 09-JAN-04 |              5 | FRIDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 10 | 10-JAN-04 |              6 | SATURDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 11 | 11-JAN-04 |              7 | SUNDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 12 | 12-JAN-04 |              1 | MONDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 13 | 13-JAN-04 |              2 | TUESDAY     |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 14 | 14-JAN-04 |              3 | WEDNESDAY   |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 15 | 15-JAN-04 |              4 | THURSDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 16 | 16-JAN-04 |              5 | FRIDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 17 | 17-JAN-04 |              6 | SATURDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 18 | 18-JAN-04 |              7 | SUNDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 19 | 19-JAN-04 |              1 | MONDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 20 | 20-JAN-04 |              2 | TUESDAY     |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 21 | 21-JAN-04 |              3 | WEDNESDAY   |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 22 | 22-JAN-04 |              4 | THURSDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 23 | 23-JAN-04 |              5 | FRIDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 24 | 24-JAN-04 |              6 | SATURDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 25 | 25-JAN-04 |              7 | SUNDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 26 | 26-JAN-04 |              1 | MONDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 27 | 27-JAN-04 |              2 | TUESDAY     |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 28 | 28-JAN-04 |              3 | WEDNESDAY   |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 29 | 29-JAN-04 |              4 | THURSDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 30 | 30-JAN-04 |              5 | FRIDAY      |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 31 | 31-JAN-04 |              6 | SATURDAY    |          0 |        1 | JANUARY  |    2004 |        1 | Total
> 32 | 01-FEB-04 |              7 | SUNDAY      |          0 |        2 | FEBRUARY |    2004 |        1 | Total
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=786c0ff2b3e382f2d46985708d9d3559)*

Comment: Wow, that's perfect! Thank you for the clear explanation too. I knew about the "date" problem, but I forgot to change it; anyway I use day_comp in order not to create any confusion. Just a question: why doesn't `select .... where day_comp = '01-JAN-%' ` work? My goal is to select all the rows about the 1st of January of any year, but probably I'm using the wildcard wrong. Thanks again

Comment: @Jado  Don't rely on implicit conversions from `DATE` to a string; if you are going to compare to a string then convert the date to a string. Use `TO_CHAR` and just output the day and month: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TO_CHAR( day_comp, 'DD-MM' ) = '01-01'`. Or, if you want to use a wildcard in the string comparison then use `LIKE` like this: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TO_CHAR( day_comp, 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) LIKE '01-01-%'`.

Comment: Thanks once again. Really clear, as usual. I've tried updating the holidays with `UPDATE table_name SET is_holiday = (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR (day_comp, 'DD-MM') = '01-01' THEN 1 WHEN .... END);` but it took way too long and when I stopped the query it froze SQLDeveloper. Any idea why?

Comment: Use the `WHERE` clause then you won't update rows that don't need changing: `UPDATE table_name SET is_holiday = 1 WHERE TO_CHAR( day_comp, 'DD-MM' ) IN ( '01-01', '25-12' )`.